# TableViewCell UI does not update for tvOS

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, tvos, uiprogressview

I have a tableview which on tap plays an audio and shows a progress view with start time and end time inside tableviewcell.Once the audio starts playing the values are updated in the didStartPlaying delegate function, where the function gets called continuously.

```
extension EpisodeTableViewCell: RadioPlayerDelegate {
func didStartPlaying(sliderValue: Float, labelValue: String, currentDuration:Float) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.audioSlider.setProgress(sliderValue, animated: false)
    print(currentDuration)
    let minutes = Int((currentDuration.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 3600)) / 60)
    let seconds = Int(currentDuration.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 60))
    print("formated: \(minutes):\(seconds)")
        self.startTime.text = "\(minutes):\(seconds)"
}
    //audioSlider.layoutIfNeeded()
}

func didStopPlaying() {
    playPauseImg.image = UIImage(named: "playBtn")
}
```

the same above code works in iOS app however for tvOS the cell UI does not update even when the function gets called.what am I doing wrong?
I also tried putting the code in view controller and reloading the tableview cell,does not work.

Comment: Is your  iOS and tvOS codebase the same? It seems to me you might accidently be updating iOS UI with some other code rather that the code you provided.

Comment: No I have created different projects for tvOS and iOS